Early divergence of YOLOv7-tiny train and val obj_loss plots
I am training a YOLOv7-tiny model and have the following observations from the training session:

the train and val objectness loss plots diverged pretty early on in the training process
the class and box losses, while not exactly diverging haven't converged either
the P, R and the mAPs seem to be ok.



The batch_size is 8 and the rest of the hyperparameters have default values as defined in the official repo's config file with some changes to the augmentation specific parameters. Below is the command i used to run the training:
$ python3 train.py --workers 4 --device 0 --batch-size 8 --data data/data.yaml --img 1088 1088 --cfg cfg/training/yolov7-tiny.yaml --weights "" --name train_dir --hyp data/hyp.scratch.tiny.yaml --epochs 200

There are 8 object categories; the train set has >30k images, validation set has >5k images.
What you guys think? I need advise with respect to interpreting the plots to identify where this is going wrong and the corrective actions that can be taken.
